# How do I fix a corrupt .cab file?

Tags: windows-xp, extract, installer, make, cab

In Windows XP, I have a folder of install files- an .exe pointing to 3 Setup.cab files. As the install progresses, it hangs on Setup2.cab as it installs tutorial_page.chm (a Help file). I have 3 options when it hangs: Abort, Retry and Ignore. Both Abort and Ignore rollback the install and exit. But if I keep pressing Retry the install will progress & this action has successfully installed the program (eventually) for me.

I AM WONDERING IF I CAN EXTRACT>RE-PACKAGE THE .CAB?

From the installed program can I grab the help.chm file and replace it into Setup2.cab for a successful install?

I am aware of the Microsoft Cabinet Software Development Kit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310618 and How To Manually Modify and Rebuild CAB Files http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176810 but 1.)want to ask if this is even possible & 2.)don't know how to make a .DDF file for Makecab.exe

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [CA Explorer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/File-managers/CAB-Explorer.shtml). You may want to investigate WinRAR and 7zip, I believe they are capable of opening CAB files, including the special Microsoft ones.

Comment: Thank you! I thought this would do the trick when I first read the description...but I cannot figure out how to compress a folder back into a CAB. My intention was to extract the corrupt CAB, replace the file that I suspect is causing the install to hang and then repackage - I don't think I can repackage a folder of files with this utility.

Comment: Regarding making a DDF file, see "Using MakeCAB"  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583149(office.11).aspx. If you can find the initial parameters, you could probably make a DDF.